# Create SymLink with GPO

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd, group-policy

I have a BATCH script that makes symlinks with `mklink`. When I run it as an administrator or as a system account (with `psexec -s -e`) it works as it should. But when I try to use it in a GPO as a startup script it gives me an error "you do not have sufficient privilege to perform this operation" on a target computer. Windows 7 Pro SP1 x64. UAC is disabled.

Batch example:

```
mklink C:\log\cmd.link.exe C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe >> C:\log\symlink.log 2>&1
```

I also tried to wrap it into a powershell script:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$env:windir\system32\cmd.exe" -ArgumentList "/c mklink C:\log\cmd.link.exe C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe >> C:\log\symlink.txt 2>&1" -Verb RunAs
```

but got the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Maybe there's another way to create a SymLink with GPO or PowerShell?

Comment: You're sure you mean a startup script and not a logon script?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure. Script that runs before logon on a system startup.

Comment: OK, in that case I have no idea what's causing the problem, but you should be able to work around it by having the startup script call `psexec` (since you know that works).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appeared that the **Group Policy Client** (gpsvc) service (since GPO scripts runs with its privilegies) does not contain the privilege to create symolic links (`SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege`):

```
C:\>sc qprivs gpsvc
[SC] QueryServiceConfig2 SUCCESS

SERVICE_NAME: gpsvc
        PRIVILEGES       : SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
                         : SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege
                         : SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
                         : SeSecurityPrivilege
                         : SeChangeNotifyPrivilege
                         : SeCreatePermanentPrivilege
                         : SeShutdownPrivilege
                         : SeLoadDriverPrivilege
                         : SeRestorePrivilege
                         : SeBackupPrivilege
```

If I want to use this privilege I should at first grant this privelege to the service. It can be done with this command:

```
sc privs gpsvc SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege/SeIncreaseQuotaPrivilege/SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege/SeSecurityPrivilege/SeChangeNotifyPrivilege/SeCreatePermanentPrivilege/SeShutdownPrivilege/SeLoadDriverPrivilege/SeRestorePrivilege/SeBackupPrivilege/SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege
```

After that you will be able to use `mklink` inside GPO scripts.

There are several caveats:

1. You should list **all** permissions (current + new). Otherwise you risk to replace all permissions with one.
2. The command needs System account permission to set privileges so you'll need to use `psexec` or GPO script (not sure).
3. If you intend to use `psexec` it will throw you an error about argument being too long. So you should save this command as a .bat file and then run it with `psexec`.

Many thanks to [@PetSerAl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) who helped me to find this out.

Answer (score 0):

I still had an issue running the `sc.exe` commands with PowerShell as a startup script via Group Policy. It was being denied access per `Start-Transcript` log file. I used the below PowerShell logic for example and it did not work for me in my case.

I tried several variations of multiple things and syntaxes using `PowerShell.exe`, `-verb RunAs`, `Start-Process` and slews of things short of running it as a local script with Task Scheduler as `SYSTEM` which I was trying to avoid.

> **Note:** This is just a general example of one of the variations that failed with the same result and transcript output as all other
> variations tried.

```
$privs = (sc.exe qprivs gpsvc).Split(":")[5..99] | % { Process { If( $_.Trim().Length -gt 0 ){ $_.Trim() } } };
$privs = $privs + "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege";
$privs = $privs -Join "/";

Invoke-Expression "sc.exe privs gpsvc $privs"
```

### A solution that works (in my case)

I used the below PowerShell logic as a startup script via Group Policy and now creating symbolic links works. To keep the example simple, I used Google Chrome for generalization.

Basically I had to manipulate the multistring registry value of the correlated permissions for the service rather than using `sc.exe` appending the needed `"SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege"` value that way.

```
#Start-Transcript -Path C:\Log\Transcript.txt

$v = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\gpsvc").RequiredPrivileges;
If ( $v -notcontains "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege" ) {
    $v = $v + "SeCreateSymbolicLinkPrivilege";
    Set-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\gpsvc" RequiredPrivileges $v -Type MultiString;
    };

$Chrome86 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome";
$Chrome = "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome";

If(!(Test-Path $Chrome86)){
    If(Test-Path $Chrome){New-Item -Path $Chrome86 -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value $Chrome -Force}
}
If(!(Test-Path $Chrome)){
    If(Test-Path $Chrome86){New-Item -Path $Chrome -ItemType SymbolicLink -Value $Chrome86 -Force}
}
```